# Alignment of text in beamercolorbox

Tags: beamer

I am trying to use 2 `beamercolorbox` and align the text inside it. [image: pdf output].

But I am trying to make, Author and Institute(Bar, HII) right aligned and at bottom of its colorbox, Title and subtitle(Foo, Hello) left aligned and at the top of the colorbox.
This is the mwe I have managed to come up with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{ru theme}[1][]{%
% \nointerlineskip

\usebeamerfont{subtitle}
\setbeamercolor{thead}{fg=white,bg=black}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em,wd=\paperwidth, ht=.4\paperheight, dp=0.5cm,right ]{thead}
\usebeamerfont{author} \insertauthor\par
\usebeamerfont{institute}%\robotocondensed
\insertinstitute\par 
\end{beamercolorbox}
% \nointerlineskip

\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black, bg=white}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=10em,wd=\paperwidth,ht=.6\paperheight,dp=0cm]{postit}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\usebeamerfont{title} {\Huge\textbf \inserttitle} \par
\usebeamerfont{subtitle} {%\robotocondensed
 \insertsubtitle}


\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\inserttitlegraphic
\end{minipage}
\end{beamercolorbox}
%\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=sapred}
}

\usepackage{multirow,caption,subcaption}
\synctex=1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{Foo}
\subtitle{Hello}
\author{Bar}
\institute{HII}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
  Hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Can you kindly help on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?  I just played with the `ht`, `dp`, and `sep` of the two colorboxes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{ru theme}[1][]{%
% \nointerlineskip

\usebeamerfont{subtitle}
\setbeamercolor{thead}{fg=white,bg=black}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em,wd=\paperwidth, ht=.4\paperheight, dp=0.0cm,right ]{thead}
\usebeamerfont{author} \insertauthor\par
\usebeamerfont{institute}%\robotocondensed
\insertinstitute\par 
\end{beamercolorbox}
% \nointerlineskip

\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black, bg=white}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em,wd=\paperwidth,dp=.43\paperheight,ht=.17\paperheight]{postit}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\usebeamerfont{title} {\Huge\textbf \inserttitle} \par
\usebeamerfont{subtitle} {%\robotocondensed
 \insertsubtitle}


\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\inserttitlegraphic
\end{minipage}
\end{beamercolorbox}
%\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=sapred}
}

\usepackage{multirow,caption,subcaption}
\synctex=1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{Foo}
\subtitle{Hello}
\author{Bar}
\institute{HII}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
  Hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, its almost like what I want. I am trying to make the texts touch the color border. I will try to play a bit more.